# Работа с сокетами на С++

Tags: сокеты, c++, visual-studio

Взял из инета несколько исходников, работающих с сокетами под UDP, запускаю ран выводит ошибку: типа не указана библиотека `stdafx.h`, вставляю ее - выходит куча ошибок: неопознаная переменная `printf`, `fget`....  в чем дело, что надо сделать, чтоб заработало?

Comment: написаны исходникики на С++

Answer (score 1):

*Исходник, который вы предоставили - работающий,* а ваши проблемы, очевидно, сугубо в непонимании особенностей `IDE Microsoft Visual Studio.`

Самый простой способ скомпилировать его - выбрать `New - Empty Project`, добавить `main.cc` и вставить в него ваш исходный код. После такой последовательности действий исходный код соберется, **но не слинкуется,** т.к не хватает ссылки на библиотеку `winsock`.

---

Линковку можно устроить через `Project Properties - Linker - Input - Additional Dependencies` или написав в коде `#pragma comment(lib, "wsock32")`.

*Второй способ крайне не рекомендуется, т.к с прагмами вообще нужно быть очень осторожным, а делать с их помощью линковку библиотек в проект - это просто глупо.*

Comment: спасибо за ответ. не могли бы вы рассписать более подробнее. я просто не совсем хорошо разбираюсь в программировании. зашел в Linker - Input - Additional Dependencies но там нет библиотеки "wsock32". может эта другая версия? я работаю на 2005. спасибо за ответ

Comment: да и не могу найти когда вставляю файл с раширением .сс

Comment: Добавить строку "ws2_32.lib" (без кавычек) в поле "Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies"

Answer (score 0):

Может быть где-то забыл поставить точку с запятой после определения класса.

Comment: Или еще какая мелочь.

Comment: да вот именно что все вроде норм. может изначально не в том окошке открываю открывал под console application

Answer (score 0):

Уверен, что подключил все заголовочные файлы? stdio.h, stdlib.h?
выложи код и вывод компилятора куда-нибудь.

Comment: ок ща сделаю

Comment: вот ссылка http://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=ru&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&q=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B+%D0%B8+udp+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B+c%2B%2B&pbx=1&oq=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B+%D0%B8+udp+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B+c%2B%2B&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=2162l5440l0l5678l14l11l1l0l0l8l264l2164l0.4.7l12l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=84d24d6baea54584&ion=1&biw=1440&bih=799
там исходник
а компилятор пишет типа возможно вы забыли включить stdafx.h

Comment: Создай в студии Console Application, и в настройках при создании проекта укажии Empty project. Потом добавь в проект файл main.cpp и скопируй туда код этого примера и скомпилируй.

Comment: сделал все как вы сказали, но мне выдает при компиляции что не возможно найти main.exe. Я зашел создал проект Win32Application Console. В настройках поставил галочку Empty project. Затем как проект открылся зашел также создать только уже не проект а файл где можно было выбрать сpp, h и еще штук 5 различных форматов. я выбрал как сказали cpp назвал main. вставил в этот файл исходник. сначала проверил succesfull вышло. начил компилировать говорит что exe по указанному пути нет. ЧТо делать?

Comment: У тебя файл создался похоже вне проекта. Ты в Solution Explorer выбери проект, нажми там правой кнопкой. Там что-то типа Add new.. есть пункта, нажми на него и добавь main.cpp в проект. потом компилируй уже.

Comment: дк выложи вывод компилятора куда-нибудь и свой исходник. Например на http://dumpz.org или http://pastebin.org

Comment: @Pentium **Вы очень смешно придумали.** Зайдите сами на главную `dumpz.org` и попробуйте найти ваш исходник. Я, например, подбирал адрес минуты 3, т.к в гугле он еще не прокэшировался - [http://dumpz.org/103102/][1]

[1]: http://dumpz.org/103102/

Comment: @Pentium а вывод компилятора где?

Comment: @Fe1iX все заработало братан, спасибо!!!